# Error in distance SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  6371.04 * acos(cos(pi() / 2 - radians(90 - `Tournament`.`latitude`)) * cos(pi() / 2 - radians(90 - 37.226)) * cos(radians(`Tournament`.`longitude`) - radians(-93.4397)) + sin(pi() / 2 - radians(90 - `Tournament`.`latitude`)) * sin(pi() / 2 - radians(90 - 37.226))) AS `Tournament`.`dist` 
FROM `tournaments` AS `Tournament`   
WHERE 1 = 1   
ORDER BY `Tournament`.`dist` ASC  
LIMIT 5
```

I can't figure out what could be possibly wrong with that statement. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`dist` FROM `tournaments` AS `Tournament`   WHERE 1 = 1   ORDER BY `Tournament`' at line 1
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: i tried to format your query using http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm but sadly there are lot of issues. please check the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `AS` is supposed to be followed by an id, not a compound identifier.

From the manual:

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

More on alias names: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

```
AS `Tournament`.`dist`
```

It is probably complaining about the dot.  Try assigning it to just `dist`.

Comment: Is there no way to assign it to the table? What if I was to have a dist from multiple tables?

Comment: @LordZardeck, he's referring to the first " AS `Tournament`.`dist` ". It's fine in the ORDER BY clause. But it's not allowed as an alias.

Comment: Try `tournament_dist` or `tournamentDist` :)

Comment: @RayToal YEAH! That will work. never thought to underscore it. Thanks!